# Significant speed issues in Windows Explorer even with recent migration of items

Tags: folder, item, limitations

Originally, I had a library of 14,000 "items" (i.e. files and folders) and learned that the moment a library hits >5,000 items, speed is significantly compromised.  It was taking 2 minutes to create a new folder in Windows Explorer view.

So I migrated the items to 4 separate libraries - all now under 5,000 items but have seen NO relief in my speed issue.  Please provide any thoughts or insights you might have.

Answer (score 2):

Explorer uses the mini WebDAV redirector. It will always be slow, no matter if you have 1 item or 10000 items (though more items means more metadata to transfer, of course). The best suggestion is don't use Windows Explorer for accessing SharePoint files. If you're using SharePoint Online, then use OneDrive to synchronize appropriate Document Libraries. On-prem, Groove is your only option or just use the web UI.

Comment: It should be noted though that using OneDrive will sync everything down to your local machine, with 14,000 files across 4 libraries, that could be a lot of storage space. 

Just watching fiddler on WebDAV requests makes my cry inside, so many http requests...

Comment: OneDrive with SPO has selective sync.

Comment: It does yes, but depending on the use, it may not be applicable